# Displaying Image on Card Applet (Siebel Open UI)

Tags: siebel

How can I display an Image on the Card (Tile) applet without disorting the edit list applet.

I have successfully implemented the Image to display on the card applet. However on the list applet the image is distorting the view.
The field on the List applet is Imagesource path, Html Type is Image control.
If this column isnt exposed on the list applet it wont be displayed on the card applet.

So how can I make the image appear on the Card applet without being exposed as an Image control html on the list applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the the object defination `[HTML Type]` on the list applet to Format Data instead of the default Encode Date.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exposing it in the applet, but setting its visiblity=hidden via CSS. I haven't tried this out, just a suggestion.

Or.. expose the field in the list applet, but at applet control level, set its HTML Type = 'hidden'

Comment: Thanks I figured it . HTML type should be set to format Data, not Encode Data.